# Python - return tuple with integer range where multiple lists of integers match

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples of ID ranges such as,

```
[(0,2), (3,6), (7,10), (11,14), (15,21), etc.]
```

Plus I have multiple lists of ID integers such as,

```
[1, 2, 4, 11, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, ...], [2, 3, 5, 10, 13, 15, 18, 20, 23, 24, ...], etc.
```

The lists are not necessarily the same length.

I'm looking for a better way to return the tuples that have at least one integer in every list within its range, such as, "1" in list one and "2" in list two match tuple list[0] (range 0-2) or "11" in list one and "13" in list two match tuple list[3] (range 11-14).

I can loop through the tuples and the lists, but that is cumbersome and slow with large lists. Is there a more efficient and concise way?

Comment: Are the lists ordered (as you show them here)?

Comment: Yes, they are ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tups = [(0,2), (3,6), (7,10), (11,14), (15,21), (600,612)]
int_list = [[1, 2, 4, 11, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24], [2, 3, 5, 10, 13, 15, 18, 20, 23, 24]]

for a,b in tups:
    f = set(range(a,b+1))
    if all(f.intersection(x) for x in int_list):
        print (a,b)
```

Using set intersection, you should be able to come up with your answer:

```
(0, 2)
(3, 6)
(11, 14)
(15, 21)
```

All tuples whose range is represented inclusively in all lists by at least one matching integer.

Explanation:  Each tuple is converted into an inclusive range.  Each range in turn is checked for intersection with all possible lists in a generator.  If any of the tuples have no intersection with a list, all() continues to next tuple. If a tuple has intersection with all lists all() returns true and the tuple (a,b) is returned to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Using the bisect module we can check if numbers in the tuple range exist in a give list by seeing if the two members of the tuple would be inserted into different indexes in that list while maintaining sorted order.  This assumes the lists are sorted but the tuples can be in arbitrary order.

```
tups=[(2,0), (3,6), (7,10), (11,14), (15,21)]
lis=[[1, 2, 4, 11, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24],
[2, 3, 5, 10, 13, 15, 18, 20, 23, 24]]
from bisect import bisect
print [(x,y) for x,y in tups if all((bisect(li,x) != bisect(li,y)) or (x in li or y in li) for li in lis)]
```

Comment: When a tuple contains number that exists in a list, this could return a wrong answer. Notice that the interval is inclusive according to the example given in the question.

Comment: This is an interesting approach I would have not thought of. Let me test it some.

Comment: This one liner is a little faster than the simple loop method I was using, but hexparrot's answer is about 25% faster than this, thus I accepted his. This still wins on being concise.

Comment: If you think about it the complexity of the intersection method grows with the size of the interval while the method of finding the two bisections is constant in the size of the interval. I'm not doubting that implementations can be slower in python for whatever reason, but thinking about it algorithmically, extrapolating the interval and doing set intersection is doing a lot of unnecessary work. Also when I timed it just now mine was faster, but timing is tricky! I bet if you gave input with larger intervals the difference would be more apparent..

Comment: Yes, timing is tricky. I was using a tuple list of around 10,000 tuples and two ID lists of a a few hundred integers. If the weight of the lists, was reversed say a few hundred tuples to 10k integer lists, the timing may be reversed as well. Yours is a great answer, and I wish I could accept both. It is just the intersection method is faster in how my lists are weighted.